# How to solve CRITICAL error of getimagesize() after data migration in Magento2.2.0?

Tags: category, product-images, magento2.2

After data migration process in **Magento2.2.0**,

When I open category page at frontend than I get this type of error in `system.log` file,

> [2018-01-02 11:56:58] main.CRITICAL: Warning: getimagesize(/var/www/html/namespace/module/pub/media/catalog/product/placeholder/default/default-image_1.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/namespace/module/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php on line 890 [] []

And also the product is not displayed on any category page.

**Anyone has idea about this problem?**

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm dealing with it right now as well.

Comment: I posted an answer. I think it will help you with this problem. **@TonyDeStefano**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long time, I seen that placeholder image does not get in getimagesize() function.(/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php on line 890)

I put an image in,

> **/pub/media/catalog/product/placeholder/default/default-image_1.jpg**

And work for me easily.

And also the product is displayed on the category page.

If anyone gets this problem then check your **/pub/media/*** image path and create required folder path and put placeholder image.

Comment: I tried the solution you suggested but its not working for me . I am still getting the same error . can you suggest me could I have done wrong ?

Comment: Please check error log and send me. or else set a default image in the proper path.